# CMake file command gives "Invalid escape sequence \." for regex rule

Tags: regex, cmake

I'm trying to do:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "^[^.]+(?!\.in)\.c")
```

to match any file named `anything.c` but not the ones names `anything.in.c` but it gives me the error

```
Invalid escape sequence \.
```

I tried

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.c")
list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES "*.in.c")
```

to not rely on regex but it looks like `list` command doesn't support regex like `file` does

Comment: I think you need to escape the period with two backslashes, not one.

Comment: @wp78de: A good habit for regex, since \ is likely special at multiple layers, is using `[]` to escape single characters instead.

Comment: @wp78de: Right, but then the regex fails in other contexts where \ is not special at an earlier layer. `[]` is always safe.

Comment: @R.. here we go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To settle the case, you need to escape the period with two backslashes, not one.

Citing from the CMake documentation on [file commands:](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/file.html)

> file(GLOB variable [RELATIVE path] [globbing expressions]...)
>
> Generate a list of files that match the `<globbing-expressions>` and
>   store it into the `<variable>`. Globbing expressions are similar to
>   regular expressions, but much simpler.

So, this is arguably not a regex but a globbing question.

The documentation on [string operations](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/string.html) notes:

> Note that two backslashes (\1) are required in CMake code to get a
>   backslash through argument parsing.

So, escaping a the `.` with `\\` is in line with the documentation.

Nevertheless, citing from the community wiki [Using CMake regexps: Escaping](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/VariablesListsStrings#using-cmake-regexps)

> Sometimes you need to escape a $
>
> - In a regex,, outside of `[]` you need `\\$`
> - In a regex, inside of `[]` you do not need anything. `[$]` is fine.
> - In a non-regex string, in front of a curly bracket you need `\${`
>
> ```
> set(blah "whatever but \${do_not_evaluate}")
> ```
>
> - In a regex string, in front of a curly bracket, you need `\\\${`
>
> ```
> string(REGEX REPLACE
>   ".*whatever but \\\${do not evaluate}"
> ```

Thus, as [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) said, in CMake it's a good habit for regex and globbing expressions using `[]` to escape special characters.

Comment: You know how to escape a `[`?

Comment: @DrumM What's your context? A string, a regex? Try it as documented above using backslashes or put it in square brackets like this: `x[]]y`  matches `x]y`, or both like this `a[][]c`  matches  `a]c`, or `a[c`